# Heading hierarchy in tex4ht

Tags: sectioning, tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

It looks like tex4ht headings start at `<h2>` for the title. The following tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{Testing headings}
\author{Alex Watson}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Top level section}

\subsection{Next level section}

\end{document}
```

processed with `make4ht -uf html5 ht-headings.tex` produces the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title>Testing headings</title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta name='generator' content='TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)' /> 
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' /> 
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='ht-headings.css' /> 
<meta name='src' content='ht-headings.tex' /> 
</head><body>
   <div class='maketitle'>



<h2 class='titleHead'>Testing headings</h2>
<div class='author'><span class='cmr-12'>Alex Watson</span></div><br />
<div class='date'><span class='cmr-12'>September 19, 2020</span></div>
   </div>
   <h3 class='sectionHead'><span class='titlemark'>1   </span> <a id='x1-10001'></a>Top level section</h3>
<!-- l. 13 --><p class='noindent'>
</p>
   <h4 class='subsectionHead'><span class='titlemark'>1.1   </span> <a id='x1-20001.1'></a>Next level section</h4>
    
</body> 
</html>
```

The headings start with `h2` for the title, then `h3` for section, etc.

I would have expected the title to be `h1`.

Maybe more significantly, if using class `book` and some `\chapter` macros, the title is still `h2` but then the chapters are also `h2`!

Is there an easy way to move the heading levels 'up one', to use `h1` for title, `h2` for the next level of sectioning, etc? (And is this a reasonable thing to want?)

A solution that works with different classes (and maybe even when splitting into multiple html files!) would be ideal, but I realise that might be asking a bit much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that it is not too logical structure, but I am afraid that changing it would break existing documents. Anyway, you can try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\begin{document}
\catcode`\:=11
% configure all sections to use our sectioning configuration
\newcommand\:setlevel[2]{%
\Configure{#1}{}{}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar
    \HCode{<#2 class="#1Head"\a:LRdir>}\TitleMark\space\HtmlParOff}
   {\HCode{</#2>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}
\Configure{like#1}{}{}
   {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi
    \EndP\IgnorePar\HCode{<#2 class="like#1Head"\a:LRdir>}\HtmlParOff}
   {\HCode{</#2>}\HtmlParOn \IgnoreIndent \ShowPar \par}
}

\ifdefined\chapter
\:setlevel{chapter}{h1}
\:setlevel{section}{h2}
\:setlevel{subsection}{h3}
\:setlevel{subsubsection}{h4}
\else
\:setlevel{section}{h1}
\:setlevel{subsection}{h2}
\:setlevel{subsubsection}{h3}
\fi


\catcode`\:=12
\EndPreamble
```

It defines a new command, `\:setlevel`, that takes two parameters, sectioning level and HTML element that should be used for that level.

[image]

```html
   <h1 class='chapterHead'><span class='titlemark'>Chapter 1</span> <a id='x1-10001'></a>my chapter</h1>
   <h2 class='sectionHead'><span class='titlemark'>1.1   </span> <a id='x1-20001.1'></a>Top level section</h2>
<!-- l. 15 --><p class='noindent'>
</p>
   <h3 class='subsectionHead'><span class='titlemark'>1.1.1   </span> <a id='x1-30001.1.1'></a>Next level section</h3>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: @michal with this config, I get stray empty heading elements inside the html title tag. Is that a known issue?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger no, that sounds strange. do you have a MWE?

Comment: Thanks, @michal.h21. I'll try to find time for a MWE.